# Ubuntu 17.10 fresh install, nvidial drivers causing boot loop

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 17.10

I am having the roughest time getting this fresh install of UBUNTU 17.10 to work properly.  I have a DELL XPS15 laptop, with GeoForce GTX 1050 mobile (NVIDIA GP170M) video card. I been tirelessly searching the web for a fix to get the nvidia drivers here: ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa to work with this machine.  I have installed the older drivers, I have installed the newer drivers, and I have installed all the drivers inbetween hoping to find one that works - all with the same result == never ending Boot loop, and no availability to log on.  I have formatted and rebuilt (reinstalled?) this machine at leat 4 times.  I have tried numerous suggestions here in this askubuntu.com forum on how to edit *.conf files, and how to disable wayland from starting at the login screen.  Nothing works.

Would love to get a system log here, but can't get into the machine.  I know I need to provide much more details.  During the bootloop, the very last line is: "Stopping user manager for UID 121".

I could really use assistance from any of you who have successfully gotten your os to work with nvidia drivers.  I will do my best to catch the system logs and put them here.

Comment: I'm using the 384.90 nvidia driver (propriety) with little problems (slight glitch but not too horrible). If you want details how to install it let me know.

Comment: @Abe Petrillo ; PLEASE, please - YES!  I would love details on how to get my nvidia drivers to work.  I need to have the extra graphics capabilites.  its a fresh install, so I am willing to try it all.

Comment: Even with nouveau "blacklisted" I am still experiencing funny behaviour with the display.  I have located drivers from the nvidia website, however, they end in *.run extension.  I will figure out how to install these and then report back here whether it worked or not.

Comment: Try following this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#NVIDIA_drivers_provided_by_the_Ubuntu_repositories. I initially installed 375 which upgraded itself to 384.

Comment: this is just crazy!! still getting boot loop.  First the installation wouldn't even proceed.  "ERROR: unable to find the development tool 'cc' in your path: please make sure that you have the package 'gcc' installed..."  Then I got "Installation has failed". So I just started over.  Booted to GRUB.  totally removed nvidia and also removed nouveau as well.  this time the installation completed, and wrote to DKMS.  But no joy....this machine will not boot.  I will keep searching, and keep trying different things.  something's gotta work sooner or later.  I will also create a bug report.

Comment: I notice the last sentence of the boot loop is "Stopping User Manager for UID 121."  And then it shows "Started Tool to automatically collect & submit kernel crash signatures."  This new install has me on the latest kernel 4.13.0-16-generic  should I consider downgrading to an older kernel?

Comment: I followed these instructions from launchpad.net bug #1705369:sudo apt purge gdm3
(optional step if lightdm is not auto installe) sudo apt install -y lightdm
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install nvidia-384.  I was able to get to the lightdm login screen, but now each time I put in my password, the login screen returns.  Essentially now instead of a "boot-loop" I am having a "login loop".  But at least I'm getting closer.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck in the bootloop too. (Ubuntu 17.10 after installing Nvidia Driver)

I think I tried all of the available suggestions but none of them worked.
I didn't recognize at the beginning that I was asked to disable SecureBoot while the installation of the driver. (Check if SecureBoot is enabled on your device)

I had to disable SecureBoot in my UEFI. After I had done this everything worked fine. I hope this helps you or someone else.